# Find power series representation for $f(x) = (4 − x)^{−3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

Find a power series representation centered at the origin for the function $$f(x) = (4 − x)^{−3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate the derivatives directly. An alternate approach is to note that $4-x=4\left(1-\frac{x}{4}\right)$. Thus
$$(4-x)^{-3}=\frac{1}{4^3} \left(1-\frac{x}{4}\right)^{-3}.$$
Now we will find the power series expansion of $(1-t)^{-3}$. 
Note that the second derivative of $(1-t)^{-1}$ is $2(1-t)^{-3}$.

We know that the power series expansion of $(1-t)^{-1}$ is $1+t+t^2+t^3+t^4+\cdots$. So we differentiate twice, and put the pieces together.

Comment: would this be a valid answer?? http://www3.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP81711a59cf48i23haf0900004ce92279063ah0d0?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=13&w=436&h=106

Comment: The second derivative is $2$ times what we want. For the second derivative, the coefficient of $t^k$ is $(k+2)(k+1)$, since we needed to differentiate the $t^{k+2}$ term twice. So the power series expansion is $\sum \frac{(k+2)(k+1)}{2}t^k$.  Now plug in $x/4$ for $t$, and don't forget to multiply by $4^{-3}$ at the end.

Comment: You are welcome. Using the *definition* of the Maclaurin expansion would work well here also. But it is important to get accustomed to manipulating known series, like the one for $\frac{1}{1-x}$, or $e^x$, to get new ones.

Answer (score 0):

The binomial theorem works for negative exponents using the identity
$$
\binom{-n}{k}=(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}
$$
Plugging in $n=3$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{-3}{k}
&=(-1)^k\binom{k+2}{k}\\
&=(-1)^k\binom{k+2}{2}\\
&=(-1)^k\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
(4-x)^{-3}
&=\frac1{64}\left(1-\frac x4\right)^{-3}\\
&=\frac1{128}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)(k+2)\left(\frac x4\right)^k
\end{align}
$$